# Проблема с конструктором по умолчанию

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

Пишу код на плюсах. Есть 2 класса, связанных отношением наследования. В конструктор класса CThree заносится новые значения для полей класса CTwo и новое значение для поля CThree. Но, при выводе значений на экран, для полей класса CTwo выводятся значения, присваиваемые конструктором по умолчанию из CTwo. Что с этим делать?

```
    //Main
    
    #include <ostream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <String.h>
    #include "CTwo.h"
    #include "COne.h"
    #include "CThree.h"
    using namespace std;
    
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
        CThree A;
        A.PrintF(); // <----- Выводит конструктор по умолчанию класса CTwo
    }
    
    
    //CTHREE.h
    
    #ifndef CTHREE_H
    #define CTHREE_H
    #include "CTwo.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    class CThree:public CTwo
    {
        protected:
            int a;
        public:
            CThree();
            CThree(string S, string SOne, double D,int A);
            virtual ~CThree();
            CThree(const CThree& arg);
    
            void PrintF();
            int Get();  
    };
    
    #endif
    
    //CTHREE.CPP
    
    #include "CThree.h"
    #include "CTwo.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    CThree::CThree()
    {
        CTwo("TEST1","TEST2",0);
        a = 0;
    }
    
    CThree::CThree(string S, string SOne, double D,int A)
    {
        CTwo(S, SOne, D);
        a = A;
    }
    
    CThree::~CThree()
    {
        
    }
    
    CThree::CThree(const CThree& arg)
    {
        a = arg.a;
    }
    
    void CThree::PrintF()
    {
        CTwo::Print();
        cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    }
    
    int CThree::Get()
    {
        return a;
    }
   
//CTWO.h
#ifndef CTWO_H
#define CTWO_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "COne.h"

using namespace std;
class COne;

class CTwo
{
protected:
    string s;
    COne obj;

public:
    CTwo();
    CTwo(string S, string SOne, double d);
    CTwo(const CTwo& arg);
    virtual ~CTwo();
    void Print();

    const string& getS();
    const COne& getObj();

    CTwo& operator=(const CTwo& arg);

    friend class COne;
    friend class CThree;
};

#endif 
    


    //CTWO.CPP
    
    #include "CTwo.h"
    #include "COne.h"
    #include <ostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    CTwo::CTwo()
    {
        s = "Конструктор по умолчанию С2";
        obj = COne("Конструктор по умолчанию С1", 128);
    }
    
    CTwo::CTwo(string S, string SOne, double D)
    {
        s = S;
        obj = COne(SOne, D);
    }
    
    CTwo::~CTwo()
    {
        s.clear();
    }
    
    CTwo::CTwo(const CTwo& arg) 
    {
        this->obj = COne(arg.obj);
        this->s = arg.s;
    }
    
    CTwo& CTwo::operator=(const CTwo& arg) 
    {
        CTwo temp(arg);
        std::swap(obj, temp.obj);
        std::swap(s, temp.s);
        return *this;
    }
    
    void CTwo::Print()
    {
        cout << "CTwo S = " << s << endl;;
        obj.Print();
    }
    
    const string& CTwo::getS()
    {
        return s;
    }
    
    const COne& CTwo::getObj()
    {
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: `CTwo("TEST1","TEST2",0);` создает безымянный временный объект, проводите инициализацию строго в списке инициализации: `CThree::CThree(void): CTwo{"TEST1", "TEST2", 0}, a{} { return; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конструкторы должны иметь примерно такой вид:

```
CThree::CThree():CTwo("TEST1","TEST2",0)
{
    a = 0;
}

CThree::CThree(string S, string SOne, double D,int A):CTwo(S, SOne, D)
{
    a = A;
}
```

А по-хорошему, даже

```
CThree::CThree():CTwo("TEST1","TEST2",0),a(0){}
CThree::CThree(string S, string SOne, double D,int A):CTwo(S, SOne, D):a(A){}
```